# How to get height and width or users local image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Working Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nbv8mb4a/

**Attempted Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3m0zekyj/

My working Fiddle allows the user to see the image before uploading. What I am attempting to do next is to obtain the height and width of the image to scale so that at least one side is 160px whereas the otherwise will be 160px or greater the image will scale.

Images lower than 160 height or width will not be allowed however I'm stuck on my tracks to get the width and height. My working code so far is below;

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({height:0,width:0,'overflow':'hidden'});
var fileInput = $(':file').wrap(wrapper);

fileInput.change(function(){
    readURL(this);
})

$('#file').click(function(){
    fileInput.click();
}).show();

function readURL(input) {
    $('#blah').hide();
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var goUpload = true;
        var uploadFile = input.files[0];
        if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
            $('#file').effect( "shake" );
            $('#file').text('You must select an image file only');
            setTimeout(function() { $('#file').text('Choose file');},5000);
            goUpload = false;
        }
        if (uploadFile.size > 2000000) { // 2mb
            //common.notifyError('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
            $('#file').text('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
            setTimeout(function() { $('#file').text('Choose file');},5000);
            goUpload = false;
        }
        if (goUpload) {
            $('#file').text("Uploading "+uploadFile.name);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
                $('#file').text(uploadFile.name);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(uploadFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Some Progress: http://jsfiddle.net/pe8wg9kx/

Comment: You are missing so many things in ur code try to be more smart while copy and paste dear !.

Comment: You could set the source of the file with an image object this way:                                                         var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';

Comment: @surajrawat I am not the best, I've been at this quite some time and this is my best progress on this part so far...

Answer (score 1):

In your attempted fiddle you are calling:

```
width = this.width(); 
height = this.height();
```

, which are undefined.
First assign the *src* attribute and then read width and height like this:

```
$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
width = $('#blah').width(); 
height = $('#blah').height();
```

Comment: Thank you [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3m0zekyj/1/). Now to reverse so the min width/height is 100px then center the image.

Comment: Wait, my fiddle does not work, it simply shows the image sorry!